# sbt not able to connect to private artifactory repository

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory

I'm trying to fetch some dependencies from my private repo, however it seems like sbt is not able to find the credentials. There's also an error in my terminal whenever I try to fetch the dependencies

```
[error] Unable to find credentials for [Artifactory Realm @ artifactory.mydomain.com].
```

I read a couple of answers already, but none of them are working for me.
What I did so far:

1) I configured my repo

```
cat ~/.sbt/repositories 
[repositories]
    local
    my-ivy-proxy-releases: https://artifactory.mydomain.com/my-ivy-release-local/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
    my-maven-proxy-releases: https://artifactory.mydomain.com/my-ivy-release-local/
```

2) I created a .credentials file

```
cat ~/.sbt/.credentials 
realm=Artifactory Realm
host=artifactory.mydomain.com
user=myuser
password=mypassword
```

3) I exported the env variable SBT_CREDENTIALS

```
export SBT_CREDENTIALS=/Users/myuser/.sbt/.credentials
```

4) I created credentials.sbt in ~/.sbt/0.13/credentials as well as in ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/credentials

```
cat ~/.sbt/0.13/credentials.sbt 
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
```

When I try to access the dependency using curl, everything works just fine.

I read about some alleged solutions already, including:

[SBT is unable to find credentials when attempting to download from an Artifactory virtual repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40411532/2254506)

[How to access a secured Nexus with sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19598435/2254506)

[How can I provide SBT credentials to my private Artifactory server from a Windows workstation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299355/how-can-i-provide-sbt-credentials-to-my-private-artifactory-server-from-a-window)

Comment: Try to put `credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials"),` in your project's settings in the project build.sbt itself.

Comment: does not help, i still get the same error

Comment: one more thing i have just found out is that my credentials got added, at least update.log says so: credentials added: Artifactory Realm@artifactory.mydomain.com myuser/********

Answer (score 2):

I copied credentials.sbt to ~/.sbt/1.0 because i found this answer:
[Where should the SBT credentials configuration go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49194710) and it looks like it does the trick.